# Stored procedure error: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_ActFTC, Line 64 Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server

After executing a stored procedure, I get the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_ActFTC, Line 64
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I have two tables in the database, `FTC_Alt` and `FichaTecnicaComp`, and I need to update the `FichaTecnicaComp` table on a given date.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ActFTC] 
AS
    DECLARE @Codigo NVARCHAR(20),
            @DataAlteracao  DATE,
            @Categoria NVARCHAR(20),
            @catord INT,
            @SubCategoria NVARCHAR(255),
            @subcatord INT,
            @Ordem INT,
            @CodigoComp NVARCHAR(10),
            @DesignacaoComp NVARCHAR(50),
            @QuantidadeComp NVARCHAR(25),
            @UnidadeComp NVARCHAR(5),
            @intRowCount INT,
            @upAction NVARCHAR(255);

    SELECT @Codigo = ft_alt.codigo   
    FROM ft_alt;

    SELECT @DataAlteracao = ft_alt.dataalteracao  
    FROM ft_alt;

    SELECT Categoria = ftc_alt.categoria
    FROM ftc_alt;

    SELECT catord = ftc_alt.catord
    FROM ftc_alt;

    SELECT SubCategoria = ftc_alt.subcategoria
    FROM ftc_alt;

    SELECT subcatord = ftc_alt.subcatord
    FROM ftc_alt;

    SELECT Ordem = ftc_alt.ordem
    FROM ftc_alt;

    SELECT CodigoComp = ftc_alt.codigocomp
    FROM ftc_alt;

    SELECT DesignacaoComp = ftc_alt.designacaocomp
    FROM ftc_alt;

    SELECT QuantidadeComp = ftc_alt.quantidadecomp
    FROM ftc_alt;

    SELECT UnidadeComp = ftc_alt.unidadecomp
    FROM ftc_alt;

    SELECT @intRowCount = @@RowCount;

    SET @upAction = 'Composição nutricional actualizada/alterada'
BEGIN
    IF (@DataAlteracao = (SELECT CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())))
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON 

        UPDATE [dbo].[FichaTecnicaComp]
        SET [Codigo] = @Codigo,
            [DataAlteracao] = @DataAlteracao,
            categoria = ftc_alt.categoria,
            catord = ftc_alt.catord,
            subcategoria = ftc_alt.subcategoria,
            subcatord = ftc_alt.subcatord,
            ordem = ftc_alt.ordem,
            codigocomp = ftc_alt.codigocomp,
            designacaocomp = ftc_alt.designacaocomp,
            quantidadecomp = ftc_alt.quantidadecomp,
            unidadecomp = ftc_alt.unidadecomp
        FROM [dbo].[FichaTecnicaComp] 
        JOIN ftc_alt ON [dbo].[FichaTecnicaComp].[Codigo] = (SELECT ft_alt.codigo
                                                             FROM ft_alt)
                     AND [dbo].[FichaTecnicaComp].Ordem = (SELECT FTC_Alt.Ordem
                                                           FROM FTC_Alt)
    END
END
```

he expected result is that data in `FichaTecnicaComp` is updated from `FTC_Alt`.
Which doesn't happen.

It should be noted that the `FichaTecnicaComp` has the following working triggers: insertion, update and delete.

If you need the code of those triggers just ask.

Comment: Easiest way is to change `=` to `IN` but still you need to find root cause - comparing with entire table is strange: `[dbo].[FichaTecnicaComp].Ordem =

         (SELECT FTC_Alt.Ordem
         FROM FTC_Alt)`

Comment: It looks like you are trying to assign values to a bunch of variables which is unecessary, and you aren't assigning them to variables at all. You are just returning the value. i.e. `SELECT UnidadeComp = ftc_alt.unidadecomp
    FROM ftc_alt;` What's the purpose of all this? Especially since you join to the table in the `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: @scsimon I want the values (all of them that belong to one "Codigo" -> this is the PK) go from one table to another. Both tables have the same amount of variables.

I started writing the sp like I was taught.

Answer (score 1):

Sub queries used in this context can only return a single value, whereas your sub queries are just returning all values of the `Ordem` and `codigo` columns.  Use the columns directly in the `ON` clause instead of as sub-selects.  You will also want use aliases instead of the full table names.  Using only the keyword JOIN will default to an INNER JOIN, which is what I'm assuming you intend to use, however explicitly stating this will help with readability.  The first sub query in your post uses `ft_alt`, instead of `ftc_alt`, but since this is the only reference to this table I'm guessing this is a typo?

```
BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON 
        UPDATE FTC
        SET 
            FTC.[Codigo] = FT.Codigo,
            FTC.[DataAlteracao] = FT.dataalteracao,
            FTC.categoria = ALT.categoria,
            FTC.catord = ALT.catord,
            FTC.subcategoria = ALT.subcategoria,
            FTC.subcatord = ALT.subcatord,
            FTC.ordem = ALT.ordem,
            FTC.codigocomp = ALT.codigocomp,
            FTC.designacaocomp = ALT.designacaocomp,
            FTC.quantidadecomp = ALT.quantidadecomp,
            FTC.unidadecomp = ALT.unidadecomp
        FROM [dbo].[FichaTecnicaComp] FTC
        INNER JOIN ft_alt FT ON FTC.Codig = FT.Codigo
        INNER JOIN ftc_alt ALT ON FTC.Ordem = ALT.Ordem     
    END
```

Comment: I want a INNER JOIN of those tables in a given condition.

`SELECT @Codigo = ft_alt.codigo  FROM ft_alt;`
`SELECT @DataAlteracao = ft_alt.dataalteracao  FROM ft_alt; `

This is not a typo, this data is on that table (ft_alt), and the "Codigo" is the same on both tables (is the PK on both tables). Ok, I can change to 

`SELECT @Codigo = ftc_alt.codigo  FROM ftc_alt`

 but the error is still the same.

Comment: @thenephrops I'm not totally sure why you're using the variables, but it doesn't look like you need them to update the FichaTecnicaComp table from the other two tables.  I updated my answer with both tables to do the update without variables.

Answer (score 0):

The error message itself says that one of the sub queries used in this stored procedure returns more than one record, while your update statement can handle only one returned row the way it is written. If you run below queries one by one, you will know where is the problem. Either you need to fix the subquery or may need to use IN instead of = in main query. I hope that helps.

```
     (SELECT ft_alt.codigo
     FROM   ft_alt)
     AND
     [dbo].[FichaTecnicaComp].Ordem =
     (SELECT FTC_Alt.Ordem
     FROM FTC_Alt
```

And also run below independently.

```
    SELECT FTC_Alt.Ordem
     FROM FTC_Alt
```